# Classifier ‘User’ does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I wish to add a profile image near every message sent in my group chat app. the image views are already present an everything is working well, but I don’t seem to get the logic in adding the image. What should I do? below is the code:

```
override fun onChildAdded(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
    val chatMessage = snapshot.getValue(ChatMessage::class.java)

        if (chatMessage != null) {
            chatMessage.let { Log.d(TAG, it.text) }

            if (chatMessage.fromId == FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid) {
                adapter.add(ChatToItem(chatMessage.text, user = User))
            }else {
                adapter.add(ChatFromItem(chatMessage.text))
            }

        }

    }
```

I am getting the error at the level of user = User.

This is the other code related :

```
 //Load user chat in chatroom > class ChatToItem(val text: String, val user: User): Item<GroupieViewHolder>() { > override fun bind(groupieViewHolder: GroupieViewHolder, position: Int) { > groupieViewHolder.itemView.idMessageTo.text = text //load our user image into the imageView of the chatmessage bubble.. val uri = user.profileImageUrl val targetImageView = groupieViewHolder.itemView.idUserImageTo Picasso.get().load(uri).into(targetImageView) }
```

Comment: I want to add the images using picasso

Comment: Thanks for the edit Frank, please can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It tells you that `User` isn't a value, you probably want `user = User()` to call its constructor (or maybe `User(some parameters)`, can't tell without the definition of `User`).

Comment: This is the other code related : `

> //Load user chat in chatroom
> class ChatToItem(val text: String, val user: User): Item<GroupieViewHolder>() {
>     override fun bind(groupieViewHolder: GroupieViewHolder, position: Int) {
>         groupieViewHolder.itemView.idMessageTo.text = text
    //load our user image into the imageView of the chatmessage bubble..
    val uri = user.profileImageUrl
    val targetImageView = groupieViewHolder.itemView.idUserImageTo
    Picasso.get().load(uri).into(targetImageView)
}`

Comment: Sorry that I can’t really say much about it, but I want to get an image from my firebase database and cache it using picasso, then pass it to the imageView in my chatlog. If you still can explicitly get my point please guide me on how to go around it maybe another way Sir. I am kinda new in the stuff :pray:

Comment: You need to look at the definition of `User` itself (search for `class User`), that code is not relevant. "I want to get an image from my firebase database and cache it using picasso, then pass it to the imageView in my chatlog" This doesn't matter for fixing this particular error. Did you try `User()` as suggested and it didn't work? If so, what was the error?